# Keeping a track of sessions in Ruby and Capybara

Tags: ruby, session, cucumber, capybara

I am using the `parallel_tests` gem to be able to run multiple features at the same time, the problem I face with my scenario is that I have user based sessions (SSO) so only one user can be logged in at a time.

To combat this I was thinking of being able to randomly select users if they are available, but tracking their `login` status globally presents an issue for me.

### My setup

Before and after each scenario a user will login:

```
Before('@login_automated_user') do
  @user = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:automated_user)
 login_steps("#{APP}")
end

After('@login_automated_user') do
 logout_steps
end
```

I was thinking of having a pool of users in an array and randomly selecting one to use and once finished return the user to the pool:

```
module UserSession
  def choose_user
    user_array = factory_girl_users.values
    if user_array.length > 0
     @user = user_array.pop
   end
  end

   def return_user
     user_array << @user
   end

  def factory_girl_users
    Hash[:user_1 => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:automated_user), :user_2 => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:automated_user_1)]
 end
end
World(UserSession)
```

This would then make my Before and After hooks look like:

```
Before('@login_automated_user') do
 @user = choose_user
 login_steps("#{APP}")
end

After('@login_automated_user') do
 logout_steps
 return_user
end
```

One issue I can see here is I'm using `@user` across two sessions (or more if I had more users) so do I need to separate them out?

Would anyone offer some tips/solutions to contemplate please?

Comment: This might solve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36721112/528617

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your exact problem, but assuming it's having single browser for few tests that run in parallel, and thus having one user's login, affecting other test that runs in the same time.

One solution, is having named session per test. Not sure it's reliable.

Other is having each of your process that parallel runs, open its own browser and then you won't have any sessions problem.
It's requiring more memory, but doesn't seem to effect tests speed.
Also instead of logging out, after each test, you could just use reset_sessions! in global teardown.