# Multiple sessions in capybara

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

### Background

I want to test logging in as multiple users on my webapp, and I am using cucumber and capybara to do this. I found [this link](https://tristandunn.com/2010/10/21/multiple-sessions-cucumber-selenium/) on how to handle multiple sessions, but unfortunately, it doesn't look like cucumber can find the `in_session` method that is defined. How can I access it?

### Cucumber scenario

```
Given I go to teacher login in Steve's browser

When I enter "Steve" in the username field 
     And I enter "StevesPassword" in the password field 
     And I click login 
Then I should see "Steve Lastname" as the current user

When I go to teacher login in Lisa's browser
     And I enter "Lisa" in the username field 
     And I enter "LisasPassword" in the password field 
     And I click login 
Then I should see "Lisa Lastname" as the current user
```

### Ruby code

```
#standard_definitions/switching_sessions.rb
When /^(.*) in (.*) browser$/ do |next_step, name|
    in_session(name) do
        step next_step
    end 
end
```

---

```
  #features/support/sessions.rb
  module Capybara
  module Driver
    module Sessions
      def set_session(id)
        Capybara.instance_variable_set("@session_pool", {
          "#{Capybara.current_driver}#{Capybara.app.object_id}" => $sessions[id]
        })
      end

      def in_session(id, &block)
        $sessions ||= {}
        $sessions[:default] ||= Capybara.current_session
        $sessions[id]       ||= Capybara::Session.new(Capybara.current_driver, Capybara.app)
        set_session(id)

        yield

        set_session(:default)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### Errors

When I run this, I get the following:

```
Scenario: multiple users                                  # features/Provebank/Provebank.feature:23
Given I go to teacher login in Steve's browser         # features/step_definitions/standard_definitions/switching_sessions.rb:5
  undefined method `in_session' for Capybara::Driver::Sessions:Module (NoMethodError)
  ./features/step_definitions/standard_definitions/switching_sessions.rb:8:in `/^(.*) in (.*) browser$/'
  features/test.feature:24:in `Given I go to teacher login in Steve's browser'
```

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is why do you need concurrent sessions for this particular test. Why not do them in series, one after the other?

Comment: Also, do you log out somehow? Where in this test does the user log out?

Comment: @ezuk The test written above is just the first part of a scenario where one user gets access to a resource and the other then tries to gets access to the resource but gets denied. For simplicity's sake, I changed "Steve gets access to resource X and sees a timeout Y" to "the page should say steve"

No, the users don't log out. But I don't see why that is relevant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned at the top of the article you linked "This is now included in the Capybara library." - except the method is named `Capybara.using_session` rather than in_session, so you don't need features/support/session.rb.  Note that the way your test is written, and the code in the link you shared, only the steps ending in "in xxxx's browser" would actually occur in a different session, not the ones you have tabbed over under those lines.  To make each of those groups of steps occur in their own sessions you would either need "in xxx's browser" on every line or instead use `Capybara.session_name = <name>` in a step which would then be used for future steps.  If setting the session_name directly you may wish to reset it to :default in an After block if you want future scenarios to default to that session.

```
# only next_step will be executed in the alternate session
When /^(.) in (.*) browser$/ do |next_step, name|
  Capybara.using_session(name) do
     step next_step
  end 
end

# all future steps will be executed in the alternate session
# you probably want to reset this to :default in an After block
Given /^I switch to (.*) browser$/ do |name|
  Capybara.session_name = name
end
```

Comment: Nah, Amab wants Sessions. He is looking [here](https://tristandunn.com/2010/10/21/multiple-sessions-cucumber-selenium/).

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 and right under the title it has "This is now included in the Capybara library."  - so there's no need for that file anymore - it's builtin to Capybara but with slightly different method names

Comment: Not trying to pick a fight. If you look closely, the Sessions module code above invokes [Capybara::Session](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session). Capybara doesn't include a Sessions class and the Session class doesn't include the above functionality.  I originally thought what you thought but then I went to look to see how it was done.  I didn't find anything.

Comment: What you can do is name your sessions. session = Capybara::Session.new(:culerity).  So perhaps you don't need to do it the way the above code does it.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56  I'm the current developer of Capybara and it definitely does include a Session class, although there is usually no need for the user to interact with it directly.  The current_session (which `page` references) is auto created based on the driver, session_name, and app instance -  https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara.rb#L319 -

Comment: I said no Sessions, not no Session. :-)  I just read the updated answer.

Comment: Sessions are stored in a private hash @session_pool - you switch between them as shown in the steps above -- either with `Capybara.using_session(name_of_session) { block to execute in that session }`  (resets to previous session name when block is finished) or by setting the current sessions name `Capybara.session_name = "some name"` - which changes the current session to the named one (both methods create a new session if needed).  The initial session name is :default

Comment: Cool. The above would be handy in the README.md file on https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: @ArnabDatta Added.  It's really only important if you care about the name of the default session though, since any tests where the session it's running in is important should be naming all the sessions used in that scenario anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly then one way of doing it is by renaming Capybara session to something like:

```
user1 = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
user1.visit "foo/bar"

user2 = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
user2.visit "bar/foo"
user1.click_on "Sign in"
user2.click_on "Log in"
```

etc.

Also look into the [`rack_session_access`](https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access) gem. Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: No, not really. I want sessions that I can refer to with on-the-fly strings rather than hardcoded variables.